# Como puedo eliminar una instancia de clase?

Tags: python, poo, tkinter, windows10

Soy un programador principiante, me he ayudado con youtube y quiero hacer una especie de videojuego de escritorio que sea puro texto (con labels) y que en cuanto mas texto se muestre, los textos de arriba se vayan ocultando o eliminando...

Por ejemplo yo tengo este codigo.

> > > 

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import Entry


root = Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.config(width=80, height=100)
fframe = Frame(root)
fframe.config(bg="black")
fframe.pack()
###########################################################################
# COLORES
azulClaro = "#0078A7"
Celeste = "#4ABDAC"
Rojo = "#A31730"
Gris = "#4E4E4E"
ColorResp = "#30b18a"
###########################################################################
# ====================================================================================================================================
# ====================================================================================================================================
# PANTALLA INICIAL
###########################################################################
Inicio1 = Label(
    fframe,
    text=("=" * len("ES IMPORTANTE QUE SEPAS QUE ES UN VERSION DE PRUEBA..."))
    + "\nHOLA...\nBIENVENIDO AL JUEGO_1\nES IMPORTANTE QUE SEPAS QUE ES UNA VERSION DE PRUEBA..."
    + "\nASI QUE NO TE PREOCUPES POR LA JUGABILIDAD..."
    + "\nAL SER UNA VERSION BETA NO TIENE SISTEMA DE GUARDADO"
    + "\nPOR LO QUE SI SE CIERRA EL JUEGO TENDRAS QUE INICIAR DESDE CERO :("
    + "\nCADA VEZ QUE TE APARESCA UNA BARRA DE OPCIONES ABAJO"
    + "\nDEBERAS ESCRIBIR EL NUMERO DE OPCION..."
    + "\nY DA -|ENTER|-"
    + "\nSI LA OPCION SON '...' SOLO DA -|ENTER|-\n"
    + ("=" * len("ES IMPORTANTE QUE SEPAS QUE ES UN VERSION DE PRUEBA...")),
    anchor="w",
    justify="left",
)
Inicio1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
Inicio1.config(
    bg="black", fg=azulClaro,
)
Inicio = Label(
    fframe,
    text=("=" * len("  SI QUIERES INICIAR ESCRIBE 'si'...  "))
    + "\n SI QUIERES INICIAR ESCRIBE 'si'... \n"
    + ("=" * len("  SI QUIERES INICIAR ESCRIBE 'si'...  ")),
    anchor="w",
    justify="left",
)
Inicio.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
Inicio.config(
    bg="black", fg=Celeste,
)
Entry1 = Entry(fframe)
Entry1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")
Entry1.config(bg="#24242C", fg=ColorResp)
###########################################################################
# ====================================================================================================================================
# ====================================================================================================================================
# CAPITULO 1
###########################################################################


def Capitulo_1(event):
    if "S" in Entry1.get() or "s" in Entry1.get():
        Inicio1.destroy()
        Inicio.destroy()
    Entry1.destroy()
```

lo que me gustaria hacer es hacer una clase que me cree los label y que yo pueda eliminarlos, así como si  usara el destroy, o que yo pueda hacer que los esconda en una scroll bar, me gustaria mucho que apoyaran, o que me dijeran donde puedo conseguir esa información.
Sin más que decir gracias comunidad.

Comment: hola, la verdad es que no entiendo bien tu planteo, pero existe del, un ejemplo:   class Hombre:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre ="Cualquiera"
        
jose=Hombre()
pedro=Hombre()

print(pedro.nombre)
del pedro
#print(pedro.nombre) si lo descomentás dará error ya que pedro no existe más.
print(jose.nombre)

Comment: Para destruir labels te recomiendo este [manual](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/54307131.html) No está de más que veas la [documentación](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf) de tkinter ahí vienen más trucos que puedes usar en tu aplicación.